# Not getting plotly graph in Jupyter notebook when I close and open the notebook again?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created many graphs using plotly library in jupyter notebook. I saved the file and exit. My graph is not appearing when I re-opened the jupyter notebook again? I need to run the code again in order to get my graph back. Also, I have sent my saved ipynb file to my friend and he is unable to see the plot..Any suggestions?

I used  py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
import datetime
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
init_notebook_mode
from math import floor
from plotly import tools
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from IPython.display import display
import plotly.tools as tls
import json
import math
from plotly.widgets import GraphWidget
import plotly.io as pi



data = [go.Bar(
            x = dplot['Boxoffice_US_Mil'],
            y = dplot['dircount'],
            orientation = 'h',
            marker = dict(
            color = 'rgb(67,262,402)'))]

# Declaring the Title and margins

layout = dict(
        title = 'Average Box Office collections by Director who have directed more than 3 movies',
        margin = go.Margin(
        l = 210,
        r = 100,
        pad = 1),
        xaxis = dict(
            title = 'Average Box Office Collection (US mil)'),

        yaxis = dict(
            title = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Director (Number of Movies)',
            tickfont = dict(
                size = 12,)))

fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Please share the problematic code

Comment: Without looking at code, I can guess from experience... did you remember to use plotly.offline.plot?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin code pasted please advise.. I used

Comment: I am getting plot. only not getting once i re-opened the notebook

Comment: it looks like you forgot `(connected=True)` in the init_notebook_mode?

Comment: Added and run. It's not coming